# best way of reading excel file and storing it in mysql table.? my table contains 4 coloumns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a excel file(xls) and My table contains 4 columns. They are id, item_number, item_name, item_group

My excel file looks lie following.

```
Row_id  Item_No Item_Name Item_Group
  1         1234      abcd        AF      
  5         6556      abcd        CD      
  7         9898      abcd       CRMD      
  8         65456     abcd       CSD
```

I am trying from 2 hours i didn't have any good example, how to aceive this..??

I want to acheive this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHPExcel package](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

```
$inputFileName = 'mails.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
foreach($sheetData as $row){
    print_r($row);
    //do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: It's very simple.. If($sheetData[1]['A'] =='Row_id' && $sheetData[1]['B'] == 'Item_No'){   //Run for loop here and write a insert query here..  }

Comment: I am on my way, trying.. Thanks for the Fast reply.. :)